# Получение полноразмерного изображения с камеры android

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Мне нужно получить полноразмерное изображение с камеры смартфона

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CONST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        }
    }
```

Данный код возвращает только превью изображения, есть ли какой-нибудь способ получить полное изображение?

Comment: Просто это сделать не получится - в Bundle полноразмерную картинку не уместить. Там надо типа как-то (примерно по рещультатам беглого гугления говорю) при запуске камеры указывать в какой файл писать фотку и потом этот файл программно загружать.

Comment: Вот в доке всё описано: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics